# Cannot remap source IP with tcprewrite

Tags: multicast, pcap, tcpreplay

I'm using tcprewrite to attempt to remap source IP of my pcap capture. The captured traffic is multicast UDP. I'm using the following cmd:
`./tcprewrite --srcippmap=10.96.225.227:172.31.22.85 --infile=/home/ec2-user/inputpcap.pcapng  --outfile=inputready.pcap`

No errors are visible
I open the output file in tshark and the source IP address has not changed
Any ideas?

`200090 105.321354 10.96.225.227 → 239.232.71.1 UDP 1372 1234 → 1234 Len=1328`
`200091 105.321414 10.96.225.227 → 239.232.71.1 UDP 1372 1234 → 1234 Len=1328`
`200092 105.322455 10.96.225.227 → 239.232.71.1 UDP 1372 1234 → 1234 Len=1328`